# on restoring the original order of row elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider numpy array `p` shown below.  Unique values 0 to 9 are used in each row.   **The distinguishing characteristic is that every row is composed of 5 (in this case) values PAIRED with 5 other values.   Pairs are formed when p[k] = p[p[k]] for k = 0 to 9**.

```
p = np.array([[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8], 
             ... 
             [6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 0, 8, 7, 4],
             ...
             [9, 8, 5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0]])
```

Examine, for example, the row:

```
[6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 0, 8, 7, 4]
```

This row pairs values 6 and 0 because `p[6] = 0` and `p[0] = 6`.  Other pairs are values (5, 1), (3, 2), (9, 4), (8, 7).  Different rows may have different arrangements of pairs.

Now, we are interested here in the **1st value of each pair (ie: 6, 5, 3, 9, 8)** and the **2nd value of each pair (ie: 0, 1, 2, 4, 7)**
I'm not sure this is the best way to proceed, but I've separated the 1st pair values from the 2nd pair values this way:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 0, 8, 7, 4])

p1 = np.where(p[p] < p)   # indices of 1st member of pairs
p2 = (p[p1])              # indices of 2nd member of pairs

qi = np.hstack((p1, p2.reshape(1,5)))
qv = p[qi]

#output: qi = [0, 1, 2, 4, 7,   6, 5, 3, 9, 8]   #indices of 1st of pair values, followed by 2nd of pair values 
#        qv = [6, 5, 3, 9, 8,   0, 1, 2, 4, 7]   #corresponding values
```

Finally consider another 1D array:   `c = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]`.

I find **`c*qv`**, giving:

```
out1 = [6, 5, 3, 9, 8, 0, -1, -2, -4, -7]
```

**QUESTION:**  `out1` holds the correct values, but I need them to be in the original order (as found in `p`).  How can this be achieved?
I need to get:

```
out2 = [6, 5, 3, -2, 9, -1, 0, 8, -7, -4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse `p1` and `p2`, which hold the original position information.

```
out2 = np.zeros_like(out1)
out2[p1] = out1[:5]
out2[p2] = out1[5:]

print(out2)
# [ 6  5  3 -2  9 -1  0  8 -7 -4]
```

---

Can also use `qi` to similar effect, but even neater.

```
out2 = np.zeros_like(out1)
out2[qi] = out1
```

---

Or using [np.put](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) in case you don't want to create `out2`:

```
np.put(out1, qi, out1)

print(out1)
# [ 6  5  3 -2  9 -1  0  8 -7 -4]
```

#### 2D Case

For 2D version of the problem, we will use a similar idea, but some tricks while indexing.

```
p = np.array([[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8],
              [6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 0, 8, 7, 4],
              [9, 8, 5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0]])

c = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])

p0 = np.arange(10)              # this is equivalent to p[p] in 1D
p1_r, p1_c = np.where(p0 < p)   # save both row and column indices
p2 = p[p1_r, p1_c]

# We will maintain row and column indices, not just qi
qi_r = np.hstack([p1_r.reshape(-1, 5), p1_r.reshape(-1, 5)]).ravel()
qi_c = np.hstack([p1_c.reshape(-1, 5), p2.reshape(-1, 5)]).ravel()
qv = p[qi_r, qi_c].reshape(-1, 10)
out1 = qv * c

# Use qi_r and qi_c to restore the position
out2 = np.zeros_like(out1)
out2[qi_r, qi_c] = out1.ravel()

print(out2)
# [[ 1  0  3 -2  5 -4  7 -6  9 -8]
#  [ 6  5  3 -2  9 -1  0  8 -7 -4]
#  [ 9  8  5  7  6 -2 -4 -3 -1  0]]
```

Feel free to print out each intermediate variable, will help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Mercury - thank you.  I especially liked the last two solutions.   I'm having one problem and am unsure how to fix it.    The code works very well for a 1D array, but p is a 2D array.   There may be an easy fix, but I'm not sure what it is.   Even my code for p1 and p2 is giving an error when p is 2D.

Comment: Yes, it won't be quite as straightforward in 2D. You can't directly index, for one.

Comment: @user109387 I've added the version for 2D. Same idea as 1D really. Just sometimes you need to maintain both row and column indices, as you are no longer working in 1 dimension.

Comment: Mercury - Excellent.   Thanks for going above and beyond.  Very instructive comments.